# How to handle Quick Switcher events in Obsidian API?

Tags: typescript, plugins, obsidian

I making a plugin for Obsidian that will need the possibility to edit suggestions in Quick Switcher. (P.S. Quick switcher is a modal window to quickly search and select files.)
Is there any event handler for Quick Switcher or alternative for it? Or i can make it with native html. (just get by id and set suggestions) [image]

I didn't find any information on the internet about handling events from Quick Switcher or somehow getting the Quick Switcher instance.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like this plugin instead: https://github.com/tadashi-aikawa/obsidian-another-quick-switcher